# Children of component are not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to build a Flip card with ReactJS, that have inside 2 others components which are : Frontside and BackSide. These components should have children such as BackgroundCard or Sectioned Card. When I test the component I'm not getting anything on the screen and there is no errors in the console!

FlipContent.js

```
function FlipContent() {
    const [setFront, setFrontState] = useState(true);
    const [setBack, setBackState] = useState(false);
    const [setFlipped, setFlippedState] = useState("");


    function FlippingCard() {

        setFrontState(setFront === true ? false : true);
        setBackState(setBack === false ? true : false);
        setFlippedState(setFlipped === "" ? "flipped" : "");

    }



    return (

        <div className={`flip-content ${setFlipped}`} onClick={FlippingCard} >
            <div className="flip-content-container" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                {setFront ? <FrontSide></FrontSide> : null}
                {setBack ? <BackSide> </BackSide> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
```

And For the FrontSide/BackSide same this as this code

```
function FrontSide({ children }) {

    return (

        <div className="flip-content-front">
            <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
```

and here how I'm trying to preview the component

```
function FlipPreview() {
    return (
        <Column>
            <Row className={css(styles.title)} wrap flexGrow={1} horizontal="space-between" breakpoints={{ 768: 'column' }}>
                Accordion <br></br>
            </Row>
            <FlipContent>
                <FrontSide>
                    <CardBackgroundComponent title="Testing" image={image}></CardBackgroundComponent>
                </FrontSide>
                <BackSide>
                    <SectionedCardComponent
                        title="Notarum Black"
                        content="Powerful and reliable, this 15” HD laptop will not let you down. 256GB SSD storage, latest gen."
                        link=""
                        linkDescription="Add To Cart"
                    />
                </BackSide>
            </FlipContent>
        </Column>
    );
}
```

Comment: So in your component you are not rendering children so you need to update two things function FlipContent(props) , pass props as argument and second update is {setFront ? <FrontSide>{props.children}</FrontSide> : null}. Kindly check and let me know

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working now but what should I do to render the children of both component? (BACK and FRONT) cuz now I'm only seeing the Front

Comment: same thing you need to do in the BackSide {setBack ? <BackSide>{props.children} </BackSide> : null}

Comment: Happy to help i will add it as answer kindly vote and accept it if it helped you

Comment: @ Marouen  kindly check the added answer , Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not inserted something inside both component `FrontSide`, `BackSide`

```
   <div className={`flip-content ${setFlipped}`} onClick={FlippingCard} >
      <div className="flip-content-container" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        {setFront ? <FrontSide> It's front side </FrontSide> : null}
        {setBack ? <BackSide> It's back-side </BackSide> : null}
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So in your component you are not rendering children. So you need to update two things.

1) Taking the props in the FlipContent component as shown below

`function FlipContent(props)`

2) <s>Use the props when rendering inside the component as shown below</s>

```
 {setFront ? <FrontSide>{props.children}</FrontSide> : null}
  {setBack ? <BackSide>{props.children} </BackSide> : null}
```

the problem is in second step is it will load all the props of children , so you need to render only the specific component. See the below one

**Update**

There are multiple ways to solve this one will list one by one

### solution one

By using the name prop of the children

```
function FlipContent(props) {
  const [view, setView] = useState("FrontSide");
  function FlippingCard() {
    setView(view === "FrontSide" ? "BackSide" : "FrontSide");
  }

  const component = React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
    if (view === child.type.name) {
      return child;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={`flip-content`} onClick={FlippingCard}>
      <div className="flip-content-container" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        {component}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-children-component-r2r1e)

### Solution Two

Instead of adding statically the names can be driven from the prop, this can't handle same component multiple times

```
function FlipContent(props) {
  const [view, setView] = useState(props.children[0].type.name);
  const ref = useRef(0);
  function FlippingCard() {
    if (props.children.length - 1 === ref.current) {
      ref.current = 0;
      setView(props.children[0].type.name);
      return;
    }
    setView(props.children[ref.current + 1].type.name);
    ref.current += 1;
  }
  let component = <span />;
  React.Children.forEach(props.children, child => {
    if (view === child.type.name) {
      component = child;
      return;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={`flip-content`} onClick={FlippingCard}>
      <div className="flip-content-container" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        {component}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-children-component-ldi8n)

### Solution three

Rendering multiple components and in the same wrapper itself.

```
function FlipContent(props) {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState(props.children[0]);
  const ref = useRef(0);
  function FlippingCard() {
    if (props.children.length - 1 === ref.current) {
      ref.current = 0;
      setComponent(props.children[0]);
      return;
    }
    setComponent(props.children[ref.current + 1]);
    ref.current += 1;
  }

  return (
    <div className={`flip-content`} onClick={FlippingCard}>
      <div className="flip-content-container" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        {component}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-children-component-y6un2)

I feel solution three is the simplest one and you have the scalable way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I changed the code like this but I'm getting the same child in both components otherwise it's different as you can see the code in preview.

Comment: So CardBackgroundComponent is loading for both Front and Back Side ?

Comment: @ DILEEP THOMAS Yes, after I click on the card it got flipped but the backside has the CardBackgroundComponent.

Comment: It is also new thing to me, two things comes to my mind one is since the child state is updating so it has the old props.children and its is rendering so somehow we need to tell react that props.children has changed do a full re render, Other one is because if it doesn't have a key

Comment: Or else try lifting up the state to FlipPreview and try it ?

Comment: useEffect( () => {
        console.log('children updated');
    }, [props.children]) check this one and check whether children is updating

Comment: const [, updateState] = React.useState();
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), [props.children]);, try this also and check

Comment: I have putten the children inside the components files and called the components (Front/Back) in the FlipContent and it's working as expected... While inspecting the one with children for some reason I still have the Front component present in the backside and it's the one being showed.. I hope you understand me..

Comment: can you add the required css, so i can check it https://codesandbox.io/s/59631010-s0-rendering-children-component-6er06

Comment: added it kindly check and accept if it worked for you

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Actually after few hours of thinking of it, I passed the children as props and it's working fine now. Frontside and Backside are now props of type "node" instead of components.

Comment: Cool if it helped you kindly accept it.. Cool Thank you